# Полупрозрачная рамка внутри картинки

Tags: css, css3

Полупрозрачная рамка внутри картинки, как сделать?

Comment: А не могли бы вы привести пример того, что надо сделать картинкой, потому что не понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вариантов исполнения может быть великое множество. Используйте, например,  `box-shadow`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://man-man.nl/app/uploads/fly-images/12011/lingerie-dame-1200x545-c.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: жесть !!! зачем такие картинки! Я же на работе?

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу знать, на работе вы или нет) Картинка для поднятия боевого духа!

Comment: А вот зачем `-moz-box-shadow` и `-webkit-box-shadow`? Такие браузеры как Chrome 4, Safari 3, FireFox 4 уже давно не надо поддерживать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov лично я в проектах использую только `-webkit-box-shadow` по привычке, да и то пора это дело сокращать. Но, многие до сих пор свято верят в необходимость поддержки старых браузеров, для них и написано.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Я бы выпилил, но это ваше дело.

Answer (score 3):

Еще вариант с `outline outline-offset`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 370px;
  outline-offset: -30px;
  outline: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://man-man.nl/app/uploads/fly-images/12011/lingerie-dame-1200x545-c.jpg" />
```

Костыль, для `IE`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 370px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 370px;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  border: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://man-man.nl/app/uploads/fly-images/12011/lingerie-dame-1200x545-c.jpg" />
</div>
```

Еще вариант с `img &&  box-shadow`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(10, 50, 51, 1);
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-image: url(http://man-man.nl/app/uploads/fly-images/12011/lingerie-dame-1200x545-c.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 120px;
  width: 520px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<img />
```

Comment: а костыль для IE11-10 есть?

Comment: Глянь в ответе...

Answer (score 1):

Внутрь:

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
```

Внешняя:

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```