# Полупрозрачная круглая рамка для фото

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: Пример изображения с круглой рамкой]

В продолжении темы [Полупрозрачная рамка внутри картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801377/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8/833696#833696) —
а если нужна рамка с закругленными углами, или полностью круглая, т.е. прямоугольное фото центр чистый, остальное пространство занято полупрозрачной рамкой, внутренняя часть в виде круга?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и на изи без SVG..

```css
.img-block {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-block img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-block .border {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно `<div class="border"></div>` заменить `:before`

Comment: @Arthur, писать стили в строчку религия не позволяет?

Comment: Это называется читабельность

Comment: Ну если только для этого)

Comment: Правки делаются для улучшения вопросов и ответов(то есть в благих целях)

Comment: И почему бы не использовать `SVG`?

Answer (score 5):

На `SVG` позже сделаю.
`mix-blend-mode` плохо поддерживается, но эффекты получаются невероятные:

```css
img {
  width: 480px;
}

.item {
  width: 480px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 5, 255, .9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144504.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Второй пример:

```css
img {
  width: 480px;
}

.item {
  width: 480px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 5, 255, .9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: url(https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144504.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144504.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Третий вариант:

```css
img {
  width: 480px;
}

.item {
  width: 480px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: url(https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144504.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: grayscale(100);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144504.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`SVG`. Пример с использованием `mask`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"/>
      <circle r="75" cx="75" cy="75"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://pravetsresidence.bg/en/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/town-house-exterior1-150x150.jpg"/>
  <rect width="150px" height="150px" fill="white" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: раз ты сделал уж на SVG то я не буду ... :))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, надо было для активности ответить))

Comment: в Лисе не видно вообще ни чего ....белое окно

Answer (score 3):

Можно также использовать для этого наслаивающийся псевдоэлемент с бесконечной тенью и `border-radius`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPNoH.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh; /* Указать нужную высоту и ширину здесь */
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* накрыть картинку полностью */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  /* бесконечная тень */
  /* fallback для IE, так как IE не распознаёт единицы vmax */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  /* для остальных браузеров, которые понимают vmax */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Для некоторых ситуаций вам вполне подойдёт полупрозрачный радиальный градиент с полностью прозрачной областью для картинки ("вырез"):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0),
    url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPNoH.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh; /* Указать нужную высоту и ширину здесь */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Я использую `0` как второе значение (`rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0`) в радиальном градиенте, чтобы не дублировать первое, так как по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) ступенька градиента не может быть меньше предыдущего значения.

> If a color-stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color-stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color-stop before it.

Comment: А разве `box-shadow` не повлияет на производительность?

Comment: @Arthur А откуда информация что `box-shadow` влияет на производительность? И по сравнению с каким методом это будет более медленным?

Comment: На одном сайте нашёл=)
— "Всё, что предполагает выполнение изменений/расчётов перед отрисовкой страницы, будет трудозатратным для браузера. Например, box-shadow, border-radius, прозрачность."
Допустим по сравнению с вашим вторым вариантом:) 
(Или я возможно не так понял эти слова)

Comment: @Arthur Ну тогда ваш комментарий подходит для всех остальных ответов тоже:) Тогда тут идеальным ответом будет отредактировать картинку в редакторе и использовать её. Расчёт градиентов мне не кажется дешёвой операцией. А ответ Максима Ленского, скорей всего, вообще "убийца" производительности, так как смешивание картинок вообще мне видится ещё более сложной операцией.

Comment: Зато креативно:D (ответы Максима).
Похоже во всех случаях выгодно использовать картинки))

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, увидите эту нагрузку только когда будете использовать GPRS интернет.. Я уверен что таких пользователей единицы и эту "нагрузку" можно проигнорировать.